# How to know if loop has optimization potential

Tags: c++, optimization

My code spends a considerable amount of time in the  following loop. I used gcc-4.8 with `-O3 -march=native` to compile the code. Since I am an absolute newbie in optimization, how do I know if the compiler did all it could? I am running on a `AMD FX(tm)-6200`

```
 float* __restrict__ ApsiPtr = Apsi.begin();
 const float* const __restrict__ psiPtr = psi.begin();
 const float* const __restrict__ diagPtr = diag().begin();
 register const label nCells = diag().size();

 for (register label cell=0; cell<nCells; cell++) {
     ApsiPtr[cell] = diagPtr[cell]*psiPtr[cell];
 }
```

ddd dumps me the following assembler code.

```
     Dump of assembler code from 0x7ffff1d32010 to 0x7ffff1d32110:¬
=>        mov    (%rsp),%rdi¬
          callq  0x7ffff1ba5ca0 <_ZNK4Foam9lduMatrix4diagEv@plt>¬
          mov    0x8(%rax),%edx¬
          test   %edx,%edx¬
          mov    %edx,%esi¬
          mov    %edx,0x34(%rsp)¬
          jle    0x7ffff1d3251f ¬
          mov    0x38(%rsp),%r10¬
          lea    0x10(%rbx),%r8¬
          lea    0x10(%rbp),%rax¬
          lea    0x10(%r10),%rdi¬
          cmp    %rdi,%rbx¬
          setae  %r9b¬
          cmp    %r8,%r10¬
          setae  %r11b¬
          or     %r11d,%r9d¬
          cmp    %rax,%rbx¬
          setae  %dl¬
          cmp    %r8,%rbp¬
          setae  %cl¬
          or     %ecx,%edx¬
          test   %dl,%r9b¬
          je     0x7ffff1d32728 ¬
          cmp    $0xc,%esi¬
          jbe    0x7ffff1d32728 ¬
          shr    %esi¬
          lea    0x40(%r10),%rax¬
          mov    %rbx,%rdx¬
          lea    -0x5(%rsi),%r8d¬
          lea    (%rsi,%rsi,1),%r9d¬
          mov    %esi,0x38(%rsp)¬
          shr    $0x2,%r8d¬
          mov    %r9d,0x4c(%rsp)¬
          mov    %rbp,%rsi¬
          shl    $0x6,%r8¬
          mov    $0x0,%r9d¬
          lea    0x80(%r10,%r8,1),%r11¬
          mov    %r11,%rcx¬
          sub    %rax,%rcx¬
          and    $0x40,%ecx¬
          movupd -0x40(%rax),%xmm0¬
          movupd 0x0(%rbp),%xmm1¬
          prefetcht0 0x1e0(%r10)¬
          prefetcht0 0x1e0(%rbp)¬
          prefetchw 0x1e0(%rbx)¬
          mov    $0x4,%r9d¬
          mulpd  %xmm1,%xmm0¬
          lea    0x40(%rbp),%rsi¬
          lea    0x40(%rbx),%rdx¬
          mov    %r10,0x40(%rsp)¬
          movlpd %xmm0,(%rbx)¬
          movhpd %xmm0,0x8(%rbx)¬
          movupd -0x30(%rax),%xmm2¬
          movupd 0x10(%rbp),%xmm3¬
          mulpd  %xmm3,%xmm2¬
          movlpd %xmm2,0x10(%rbx)¬
          movhpd %xmm2,0x18(%rbx)¬
          movupd -0x20(%rax),%xmm4¬
          movupd 0x20(%rbp),%xmm5¬
End of assembler dump.¬
```

Comment: You are showing an assembly dump with such instructions as `jbe    0x7ffff1d32728` but there are no addresses in the dump! Anyway, it appears your code was automatically vectorized. The only possible gain remaining would be if there are alignment hypotheses that you could inform the compiler of so that it does not need to generate code that handles misaligned arrays or arrays without a round size.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I removed the jump addresses since they are kinda hard to read with nested templates, would they be of interest? How do i find out if arrays are missaligned then ?

Comment: It's safe to assume that the compiler did all it could with the information available to it. You're now into micro-optimisation, which is rarely productive. You might save a few machine cycles per iteration, but this is unlikely to deliver an improvement in performance commensurate with the time taken for you to achieve it. You should profile your code and work on the identifiable bottlenecks.

Comment: @MikeW Good to know. But could micro-optimisation be reasonable if my code spends some weeks (accumulated) in that loop? The nCells is in the order of Millions and the loop needs to be called over and over again.

Comment: Maybe time to look into optimized algorithms, if any applicable ones exist - e.g. sparse matrix techniques etc.

Comment: @user1204242 You've posted here about 60 instructions. Let's assume that equates to 120 machine cycles, and any optimisation you can apply saves 6 cycles per iteration. That's 5% which, over a 3-week execution period, will save about a day. Is that reasonable, given that there's no guarantee that you could achieve it? There might be much larger savings to be had elsewhere. As I said - you should profile your code first.

Comment: I can only second Mike W. **Focus on algorithms, not on micro-optimization.** By revising the algorithm that calls this loop, you might gain a lot more than spending time on this micro-optimization. Perhaps some of those calls to this loop can be avoided? In my experience, profiling and revising the algorithmic steps can lead to significant speed-up with moderate efforts. With micro-optimizations, you usually shave off a few percents. It's your choice.

Comment: Do you know how far you are from utilizing all processing units in the CPU? There are two limiting factors: memory bandwidth and number of (32/64 bit) ALU operations per second.

Comment: Are you sure your generated code matches your C++ code ? The generated code is using double precision loads/stores/multiplies, whereas your source code uses `float`s ?